# Angular 2 binding form to an object

Tags: angular, data-binding

By navigating to http://servername/some-form/1 I open up a form and getting a dataset from a service with the ID 1. This dataset is an javascript object.

edit:
*Now what is the difference/advantage/disadvantage of using a formbuilder instead of two way bindung to a property inside an object?*

example:

```
{
  firstname:"test",
  lastname:"test",
  surname:"test"
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax

Comment: Ok. I got that. But what is the difference/advantage/disadvantage of using a formbuilder instead of two way bindung to a property inside an object?

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: Do you mean reactive forms..https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html

Comment: Yes. What is the Advantage of using those?